# How does the Federal Reserve learn from its mistakes?

Tags: federal-reserve

How does the Federal Reserve learn from its mistakes?

Establishments use internal reviews, post-mortem analyses and other means to improve upon existing mechanisms and governance framework, but I am wondering if this is something the Federal Reserve would even do. Is there any such framework, or the quality of the governance is entirely dependent on who gets nominated and there's no continual improvement or body of knowledge that gradually improve the governance of the Federal Reserve?

Comment: You're going to have to clearly define mistake. Just because an outcome was not what the public desires doesn't mean that they had made an error in judgement or that the outcome was not the intended one by the federal reserve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fed doesn't learn from its mistakes. It relies on the collective wisdom of its Board members and their experiences, which ebbs and flows as personnel change over time.